# ruby on rails drop down onchange submit

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code in my view located in "\app\views\deployment_group" named make_deployment_group.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :folder_name, :remote => true, :method => "get", :url => {:action => "show_workflow_list"} do |f| %>
            <%= f.select :foldernames, options_for_select(@folders, @folders.first)%><br /><br />

            <%= hidden_field_tag 'selected_domain', params[:domain_selected] %>
            <%= hidden_field_tag 'user_name', params[:username] %>
            <pre><%= f.submit "Submit"%></pre>
            <% end%>and my `js.erb` file for the action
```

show_workflow_list.js.erb: located at "\app\views\deployment_group" as show_workflow_list.js.erb

```
$('#workflow_selection').html("<%=j render "show_workflow_list" %>");
```

My application.html.erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Authorize</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Now i want to remove the submit button and render the `show_workflow_list` partial in the `<div>` tag on my view whenever there is a change in the drop down. of folders.

Please help,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must to do this in JQuery. In a js file your must have something like this, in your app/assets/application.js, when the document is ready :

```
$('#foldernames').change(function() {
  $('#folder_name').submit()
});
```

Or this, if you use coffeescript :

```
$('#foldernames').change = () ->
  $('#folder_name').submit()
```

It will works. It's unobostructive javascript! It will submit the form when you change the select, call your action in your controller in a ajax function and execute the content in your js.erb file.

Comment: i added the same thing in my show_workflowz-list.js.erb file. But how does it know that it should render  "('#workflow_selection').html("<%=j render "show_workflow_list" %>"" this part. In my server on the command prompt, i did not see any parameters being passed to show_workflow_list when i change the value in the drop down

Comment: Your code should be in file app/views/my_controllers/show_workflow_list.js.erb.

Comment: hi, the js.erb file is in my views, otherwise even the submit button should not have worked. Now i modified my js.erb file like this "$('#foldernames').change(function() 
{   $('#folder_name').submit()
 $('#workflow_selection').html("<%=j render "show_workflow_list" %>")
  });" so that it can render the show_workflow_list after $('#folder_name').submit() but i'm a jquery starter so i think there something obviously wrong here. I have one more small question - do i need to add some code like ":onchange" in my f.select tag in the main view?

Comment: also, my layout is having "<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>" should i change it to defaults or prototype instead of "application"? Please help.                                       Thanks

Comment: No, you don't need to add anything in you select_tag.

Comment: You don't need to your javascript_include_tag too.

Comment: No :( i'm still trying i think i have to satisfy with the submit button only. I removed all the changes and i'm back to original position. Here is my show_workflow_list.je.erb file -> "$('#workflow_selection').html("<%=j render "show_workflow_list" %>");" and my view as is in the above posted question. Let me know what all changes that need to be, i will edit my question to make it more clear

Comment: Please, can you edit your question and put all your code with the locations?

Comment: Thank for the help. It still does not work but i think i figured out the problem. I had deleted the "//= require_tree ." line in my application.js file because my windows systems says "can't convert Encoding into String" if there is require_tree and now this change has to be noted by application.js and as there is no require_tree, it is not able to identify the change in the children. Thanks again for your help, i will try it on a proper system and will let you know

Comment: You can replace it be require_self

Comment: hi i posted a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658326/ruby-on-rails-jquery-submit-a-form-as-js).. this time the problem is a lot more clearer to me i think you can find the solution easily